# Как можно протестировать свою игру в Google Play Services Без ожидание 4 дней

Tags: unity3d, google-play-console

Я добавил Рейтинги в Google Play Console и мне нужно увидеть как они работают без ожидание 4 дней. можно ли как нибудь протестировать знаю что есть тестирования(Внутр. откр и тд) но не знаю будет ли там работать фукнция Google Play.

Comment: Я использовал внутренне тестирование. Когда переходишь по ссылке, появляется белый экран и дальше не переходит. По правилам приложение в Google play должно проверится. На проверку заявлено двое суток. Однако мне пришлось ждать 3 недели чтобы наконец-то можно было его установить.

Comment: Если необходимо проверить только сервисы Google play, то необязательно нужно опубликовывать приложение. Достаточно просто довести до рабочего состояния сами сервисы и использовать тот же ключ SHA1. (Поищите в интернете, это возможно)